# How to open all type of file in new tab using Desktop.getDesktop() method?

Tags: java

I am working on java project. I am working on issue to open local files (of all types) from my system into new tab.
 Here is the code I have applied for opening the files in browser:-

```
String myLocalPath=spath; //spath is path of my local file
            try {
                Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(spath));
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I am facing the issue that all type of files are not getting open in new tab. ie. 
html file is getting open in new tab of current browser from where I am trying to open it,

txt file is getting open in IE browser

Xml file is getting open in notepad etc.

I want to open all type of file in new tab of same browser, whether the file is pdf, txt, xml,png or any other.

I would be thankful if anyone could help me out in finding my solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the browse method delegates the opening function to the default SO association file types.

From the `browse(URI uri)` documentation class:

> Launches the default browser to display a {@code URI}.
>   If the default browser is not able to handle the specified
>   {@code URI}, the application registered for handling
>   {@code URIs} of the specified type is invoked. The application
>   is determined from the protocol and path of the {@code URI}, as
>   defined by the {@code URI} class.

As per the `Desktop` class this is what it handles:

> The {@code Desktop} class allows a Java application to launch
>   associated applications registered on the native desktop to handle
>   a {@link java.net.URI} or a file.

- launching the user-default browser to show a specified
        URI;
- launching the user-default mail client with an optional
        {@code mailto} URI;
- launching a registered application to open, edit or print a
        specified file.

See the full specification here: [Class Desktop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html)

Comment: I have also tried this code:-    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(myLocalPath)); 
Any other solution other than I requested which could fix my issue will also be thankful.

Comment: The answer that I provided you is to show you from the documentation that you can't do what you want from the Desktop class.

Comment: Ok..than other than Desktop class what can I use to fix my issue?

Comment: Unfortunatelly I don't know a single class that can do such a thing. The workaround would be to configure yoor browser to associate it with that file types so it can open that files by default. If it isn't possible to the SO to handle it, imagine your program. The elegant way would be implement a file type reader to each file type but it would take ages and lots of work.